# Zabbix disk count detection in linux communicating variable count

Tags: zabbix

monitor a few linux devices via zabbix. I use the "Linux by zabbix agent" template for monitoring
which detects drives from what I see by the Mounted filesystem discovery rule.
there are always two disks in my machines and in zabbix charts I see these two disks. My question is how to write a rule now and what to do to get information that one of the disks is not visible and has unmounted

I tried to understand it but I can't I expect help in creating this trigger to display information in problems about missing one disk

Answer (score 0):

Since `vfs.fs.size[]` item goes unsupported when the filesystem is no longer mounted, you will need a user parameter. Example:

```
UserParameter=vfs.fs.ismounted[*],cat /proc/mounts | grep ' $1 ' | wc -l
```

See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/userparameters